# Postgres DB - Split records in a table and download to excel

Tags: postgresql

I have a table that consist of 20k records. I want to export it to excel. Is it possible to split the total records equally to 5 different excel or sheet?

Let say 20k records to 5 different excel. So each excel will contain 4k unique records.

Comment: why do you want to split data, did you get a memory issue while you saved it in one block?

Comment: Postgres has no tools to export to Excel. Using `psql` you can export the rows to a CSV file that can be opened by Excel. You could export using a WHERE condition to limit the number of rows. But Excel should be able to open a file with 20k rows without problems

Comment: You can use `SELECT` with `OFFSET` and `LIMIT` to export 4 sets of records to CSV